# How to make the api generated from .yaml read the header of the request

Tags: java, gradle, yaml, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to use Jwt tokens for user authentication in a project with different microservices.

So, if I want to request something from one microservice to another, I have to have a token in the header of the http request, but I don't have the data necessary to generate a new request (email and password)

Therefore, whenever a user sends a request, I wanted to get the token from the header of the request, and then forward it to the next microservice when doing a request myself.

We use postman to send requests, and there is an Authorization header that contains the token.

I tried writing this into my .yaml file to get the header:

```
paths:
  /submission:
    post:
      security:
        - api_key: [ ]
      tags:
        - submission
      summary: Add a new submission to the system
      description: Add a new submission to the system
      operationId: addSubmission
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                submissionData:
                  type: string
                  description: "Stringified JSON of submission data"
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
                  description: "Text file to upload"
        required: true

      parameters:
        - name: Authorization  # Include Authorization as a parameter
          description: jwt token of the request
          schema:
            type: string
          in: header

      responses:
        # responces

  securitySchemes:
    api_key:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

but what I got was this

```
    default ResponseEntity<String> addSubmission(
        @Parameter(name = "Authorization", description = "jwt token of the request", in = ParameterIn.HEADER) @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = false) String authorization,
        @Parameter(name = "submissionData", description = "Stringified JSON of submission data") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "submissionData", required = false) String submissionData,
        @Parameter(name = "file", description = "Text file to upload") @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file
    ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }
```

which just added it as a parameter as provided by the body. I tried, and having Authorization only in the headers and not body doesn't work.

What did I do wrong? Is what I am trying to do even possible?
If not, what would be the best way to do this?